# In a Python Azure Function, is it possible to use Dask?

Tags: python, azure-functions, dask

I have a Python Azure Function that I an run successfully on my local machine, but is failing when deployed to Azure.

I believe the Dask package is causing issues. Below is a snippet of my code where the Dask is setup,

```
client = Client()

docContentBag = db.from_sequence( zip( range( len([stringVariable])), [stringVariable] ) )
```

Azure outputs the following logs,

```
2023-09-21T05:29:53Z   [Error]   distributed.diskutils - ERROR - Failed to clean up lingering worker directories in path: %s

2023-09-21T05:29:53Z   [Error]   OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/site/wwwroot/dask-worker-space/global.lock'
2023-09-21T05:29:53Z   [Error]   distributed.nanny - ERROR - Failed to initialize Worker

2023-09-21T05:29:53Z   [Error]   OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/home/site/wwwroot/dask-worker-space/worker-95w2an2l'
2023-09-21T05:29:53Z   [Error]   distributed.nanny - ERROR - Failed while trying to start worker process: [Errno 38] Function not implemented: '/home/site/wwwroot/dask-worker-space/worker-95w2an2l'
```

Is it possible to use Dask in Azure functions?

Comment: I tried using this code in my init.py - 
import os
from azure.functions import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask.bag as db



def main(req: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    
    os.environ['PYTHONUSERBASE'] = '/tmp'

    client = Client()
    stringVariable = "Hello, World!"
    docContentBag = db.from_sequence( zip( range( len([stringVariable])), [stringVariable] ) )
    return HttpResponse(f"Dask setup complete. {docContentBag.compute()}", status_code=200) and these packages in my requirements.txt- azure-functions
dask[complete]

Comment: And I am able to run the function successfully refer here - https://i.imgur.com/fTbuKZD.png

Comment: Can you share your init.py code and requirements.txt?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe should *not* be trying to spawn processes within the container. If you simply omit the `client=` line, you will instead default to the builtin threaded scheduler, which is much simpler and runs with far fewer system requirements. Of course, this supposes that your code you are running is friendly with the GIL and makes good use of threads.